Enable session replication in Payara server 5.2020.6 with embedded hazelcast
I am trying to enable session replication in my payara server instances using embedded hazelcast. Currently, I have my application deployed on different pods in an openshift environment, each embedded hazelcast is using multicast to discover other application pods to form a data grid together and I am able to verify that the different payara server embedded hazelcast instances are able to discover each other. I
To allow session replication here is what I have done so far:

Included <distributable /> tag in my web.xml
set
${Cluster-Config}.availability-service.web-container-availability.persistence-type=hazelcast

I used this command to set web container availability to hazelcast. My question with this, how does the separate Hazelcast instances in the datagrid reference the same server config or Cluster config. Is this something I need to create in one instance and have other instances refer to it once the datagrid is created by manually running asadmin commands? Or is the requirement just to have all the settings for the server config in those seperate payara server instances to be exactly the same?
I would really appreciate if someone could help me think this through, the payara server documentation and their online blog series has not really been useful.
